# How to render 1k pdf files using jsreport and jsreport Chrome Pdf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, jsreport

I'm trying to be able to generate 1k reports using and endpoint with Express.js, I pass an array in a JSON, the API goes over it and in a forEach loop, then every object is used to **scrape** a portal, get the response, and create a PDF file...

This approach pseudo work, but I'm pretty sure that there are some concurrency problems... because, if I pass 2 items in the JSON array the API can create the 2 PDF files without a problem, but if I pass 300 the API creates randomly 50... or 60 or 120.

This is my jsreport config

```
const jsReportConfig = {
  extensions: {
    "chrome-pdf": {
      launchOptions: {
        timeout: 10000,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
      },
    },
  },
  tempDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, './../../temporal/pdfs'),
  templatingEngines: {
    numberOfWorkers: 4,
    timeout: 180000,
    strategy: 'http-server',
  },
};
```

I setup the jsreport instance like this

```
jsreport.use(jsReportChrome());
jsreport.use(jsReportHandlebars());
jsreport.init()
```

And, this is how I render the reports, the `checkInvoiceStatus` function is used as an HTTP call that returns an HTML response that is injected in the Handlebars template.

```
const renderReports = (reporter, invoices) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const templateContent = await readFile(
        path.resolve(__dirname, './../templates/hello-world.hbs'),
        'utf-8',
      );
      invoices.forEach(async (invoice) => {
        try {
          const response = await checkInvoiceStatus(invoice.re, invoice.rr, invoice.id)
          const $ = await cheerio.load(response);
          const reporterResponse = await reporter.render({
            template: {
              content: templateContent,
              engine: 'handlebars',
              recipe: 'chrome-pdf',
              name: 'PDF Validation',
              chrome: {
                displayHeaderFooter: true,
                footerTemplate: '<table width=\'100%\' style="font-size: 12px;"><tr><td width=\'33.33%\'>{#pageNum} de {#numPages}</td><td width=\'33.33%\' align=\'center\'></td><td width=\'33.33%\' align=\'right\'></td></tr></table>',
              },
            },
            data: {
              taxpayerId: 'CAC070508MY2',
              captcha: $('#ctl00_MainContent_ImgCaptcha').attr('src'),
              bodyContent: $('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlResultados').html(),
            },
          });
          reporterResponse.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoice.id}.pdf`));
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          reject(new Error(JSON.stringify({
            code: 'PORTAL-PDFx001',
            message: 'The server could not retrieve the PDF from the portal',
          })));
        }
      });
      resolve();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(new Error(JSON.stringify({
        code: 'PORTAL-PDFx001',
        message: 'The server could not retrieve the PDF from the portal',
      })));
    }
  });
```

I don't know why, but this function is terminated in **500ms**, but the files are been created after 1 minute...

```
app.post('/pdf-report', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { invoices } = req.body;
  repository.renderReports(reporter, invoices)
    .then(() => res.status(200).send('Ok'))
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Alongside the code presented by @hurricane, I had to change the jsReport config to this

```
const jsReportConfig = {
  chrome: {
    timeout: 180000,
    strategy: 'chrome-pool',
    numberOfWorkers: 4
  },
  extensions: {
    'chrome-pdf': {
      launchOptions: {
        timeout: 180000,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
      },
    },
  },
  tempDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, './../../temporal/pdfs'),
  templatingEngines: {
    numberOfWorkers: 4,
    timeout: 180000,
    strategy: 'http-server',
  },
};
```

Comment: Instead of doing foreach you can go with a queue where once the task is completed you can process the next. Don't know about jsreport but if jsreport uses puppeteer in the background then this is going to be a very costly operation. so I suggest leaving a considerable timegap between processing the items.

Comment: also you are not checking if the file write operation is ended here reporterResponse.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoice.id}.pdf`));

Comment: So, in a few words, I should add a job scheduler like [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)? or how do you do implement a queue??... Sorry if I'm not getting this clear

Comment: Yes Bull looks like a queue. You can follow that. But first try closing the writestream bug and see if your issue still persists

Comment: Any thoughts on how to achieve this? This part is a little bit confusing to me

Comment: I think user @hurricane has given you a solution which solves the writestream issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your structure it is easy to solve your problem with `writeFileSync` function instead of using writeStream. But it does not mean it is the best approach. Because you have to wait for each render and each write file process to start another one. So i would suggest to use `Promise.all` that you can run your long processes at the same time. That means you will wait only for longest process.

**Quick win - Slow process**

```
reporterResponse.result.pipe
```

Change this line with

```
   fs.createFileSync(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoice.id}.pdf`);
```

**Better Approach - Fast process**

```
const renderReports = (reporter, invoices) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const templateContent = await readFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, './../templates/hello-world.hbs'),
      'utf-8',
    );
    const renderPromises = invoices.map((invoice) => {
      const response = await checkInvoiceStatus(invoice.re, invoice.rr, invoice.id)
      const $ = await cheerio.load(response);
      return await reporter.render({
        template: {
          content: templateContent,
          engine: 'handlebars',
          recipe: 'chrome-pdf',
          name: 'PDF Validation',
          chrome: {
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            footerTemplate: '<table width=\'100%\' style="font-size: 12px;"><tr><td width=\'33.33%\'>{#pageNum} de {#numPages}</td><td width=\'33.33%\' align=\'center\'></td><td width=\'33.33%\' align=\'right\'></td></tr></table>',
          },
        },
        data: {
          taxpayerId: 'CAC070508MY2',
          captcha: $('#ctl00_MainContent_ImgCaptcha').attr('src'),
          bodyContent: $('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlResultados').html(),
        },
      });
    });
    const renderResults = await Promise.all(renderPromises);
    const filewritePromises = results.map(renderedResult => await fs.writeFile(`./temporal/validatedPdfs/${invoice.id}.pdf`, renderedResult.content));
    const writeResults = await Promise.all(filewritePromises);
    resolve(writeResults);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    reject(new Error(JSON.stringify({
      code: 'PORTAL-PDFx001',
      message: 'The server could not retrieve the PDF from the portal',
    })));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, when I used the code didn't work the first time because the problem you told me... Puppeteer started a new chromium instance per rendering... So, I found a config that help me on this.